# How can we data wrangling to obtain shown ratio/proportion chart shown

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

Goal is to produce a visualization indicating ratio.
Please help us how can we produce such ratio chart (high lighted) in R ?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

# Dataset creation
df <- data.frame(cls = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)),
                 grd = c("A1",rep("A2",3),rep(c("B1","B2"), 2)),
                 typ = c(rep("m",2),rep("o",2),"m","n",rep("p",2)),
                 pnts = c(rep(1:4,2)))

df

#### Data wrangling
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(cls) %>%
  summarise(cls_pct = sum(pnts))
df1

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(cls,grd) %>%
  summarize(grd_pct = sum(pnts))
df2

df3 <- df %>%
  group_by(cls,grd,typ) %>%
  summarise(typ_pct = sum(pnts))
df3

#### Attempt to combine all df1,df2,df3
# but mutate and summarise are mixing up leading to wrong results
df3 %>% 
  group_by(cls,grd) %>%
  mutate(grd_pct = sum(typ_pct)) %>%
  group_by(cls) %>%
  mutate(cls_pct = sum(grd_pct))
```

Attempt to visualize all the ratios in 1 chart

```
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(cls:pnts),
               names_to = "per_cat",
               values_to = "percent") %>%
  ggplot(aes(cls,percent, col = typ, fill = grd)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

plot of the same.
[image: ggplot barplot]

Comment: You could do a join and then divide `df1 %>% mutate(per = cls_pct/sum(cls_pct))
;df2 %>% left_join(df1) %>% mutate(pct = grd_pct/cls_pct)` `df3 %>% left_join(df2) %>% mutate(pct =typ_pct/grd_pct)`

Comment: The column format is  not clear.  Are those columns again split up

Comment: @akrun, Sorry for confusion in column. yes, they also need to be split and therefore A and B also has .5 each value in the final column. 

However, since the solution is already there. Can you please help us visualize all the 3 categories in 1 graph as my image above shows . It can be ggplot or sunburst or anything except facets because my real data has many variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT -- added formula version with more useful output for visualization.

---

ORIG: At this point it may be worth making a function to reduce copying and pasting, but this may get you what you need:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(cls) %>%
  mutate(per1 = sum(pnts),
         per1_pct = per1 / sum(per1)) %>%
  group_by(cls, grd) %>%
  mutate(per2 = sum(pnts),
         per2_pct = per2 / sum(per2)) %>%
  group_by(cls, grd, typ) %>%
  mutate(per3 = sum(pnts),
         per3_pct = per3 / sum(per3)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

EDIT: Here's a general function to calculate the stats for a given grouping, making it easier to combine a few groupings together in long format better suited for visualization.

```
df_sum <- function(df, level, ...) {
  df %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    summarize(grp_ttl = sum(pnts)) %>%
    mutate(ttl  = sum(grp_ttl),
           pct  = grp_ttl / ttl) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(level = {{ level }} )
}

df_sum(df, level = 1, cls) %>%
  bind_rows(df_sum(df, level = 2, cls, grd)) %>%
  bind_rows(df_sum(df, level = 3, cls, grd, typ)) %>% 
  mutate(label = coalesce(as.character(typ),   # This grabs the first non-NA
                          as.character(grd),
                          as.character(cls))) -> df_summed

df_summed %>%
  ggplot(aes(level, grp_ttl)) +
  geom_col(color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(label, "\n", grp_ttl, "/", ttl)),
            color = "white",
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_reverse() +   # To make level 1 at the top
  coord_flip()          # To switch from vertical to horizontal orientation
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer @Jon Spring. 
Thanks for solution.

Can we use ggplot2 or sunburst or something to somehow show the proportion of 3 categories in 1 graph (e.g. bar-like chart) ? differentiating with colors or fill ?

**please dont suggest facets as my real data has many variable**
```
# Attempt to visualize all the ratios in 1 chart

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(cls:pnts),
               names_to = "per_cat",
               values_to = "percent") %>%
  ggplot(aes(cls,percent, col = typ, fill = grd)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()

Comment: Edited with a more generalized approach which outputs the fractions and annotations you drew.